# How to eliminate a sub-directory level from all URLs in Website

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website and I just setup an os shopping cart (ie., Magento)

I installed the cart in a sub-directory off the document root as /magento/ per the installation guidelines.

So my web site cart's URL is http://mydomain.com/magento/

I have no public pages off the document root and I actually want my cart to be my home page -- in other words, I want `http://mydomain.com/magento/` to resolve as `http://mydomain.com/`

Is it possible? Can I use mod-rewrite to make it happen? If so, can you suggest what the mod-rewrite directives would look like?

Or is it simply a permanent redirect like:

```
redirect 301 /magento http://mydomain.com/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/magento
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /magento/$1
```

In this way, it should replace everything with `/magento` in front of it. So, you can have your links to point on your root.

I've edited and tested it, it works.

Now that I've better read your question, it seems you want to redirect only the home page, and not the whole site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /magento/
```

Comment: Ok, thanks @Zagorax. But when I test it, it seems to work backwards. It defaults to taking me to `http://mydomain.com/magento/` when I want a re-write of `http://mydomain.com/magento/` to go to `http://mydomain.com/`

Comment: @frank13, Look at the URL bar. It shows you `http://mydomain.com/` while it loads `http://mydomain.com/magento`, where you actually have your cart. Have i misunderstood your question?

Comment: @frank13, I've edited my post, check if the second solution was the one you were looking for. :D

Comment: It stills goes backwards on my machine -- ie achieves the opposite result. I need everything to have `/magento/` eliminated. @Zagorax

Comment: @frank13, Ok, here is the rule the erase magento: `RewriteRule ^magento /`... but I don't understand how people will get the cart after this rule will be added.